# Force itemize inside description onto a new line

Tags: itemize, description

I have an itemize inside a description, like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in,hmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Definition 1]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{itemize}
  \item[Definition 2]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Four
    \item Five
  \end{itemize}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

However, despite the `style=newline` (which works for normal text in a description item), the first item of the itemize is on the same line as the definition:

[image: Example rendering]

How can I force the itemize to begin on a new line?

Ideally, I am looking for a solution I can put in an `options.sty` rather than an in-line solution involving mboxes etc. (the actual latex causing me a problem is being generated from reStructuredText via pandoc, however the snippet above reproduces the problem).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Apologies - first post! I have updated my snippet to include everything that I have in my test document - I hope it is sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try some variation on the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in,hmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt,before=\leavevmode\vspace{-1.5em}}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Definition 1]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{itemize}
  \item[Definition 2]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Four
    \item Five
  \end{itemize}
  \item[Definition 3]
  This is a normal description.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

This important bit is the `\setlist[itemize]{...}`. This gives:

[image]

Comment: This works really well for the nested lists. However, it doesn't play nice with `\setlist[description]{style=nextline}` which I am using for definition lists with 'normal' text - it results in large gaps between the definition and the first list item.

Comment: @mkjpryor This was why I removed the `\setlist[description]{style=nextline}`:) I've modified the example above so that it now uses the `vspace` as suggested by Harish Kumar in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

Very easy. Start `itemize` with a *empty*  item. Like this `\item[]`. This works well with `\setlist[description]{style=nextline}` (and `enumerate`) and if you want to align with  description you can add `\setlist[itemize,enumerate]{leftmargin=*}`.

Further, if you want lists with the normal separation of the text should use the settings `\setlist[itemize,enumerate]{itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}`
Here the complete code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in,hmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}
\setlist[itemize,enumerate]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Definition 1]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[]
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{itemize}
  \item[Definition 2]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[] 
    \item Four
    \item Five
  \end{itemize}
  \item[Definition 3] This is a specification for \ldots
  \item[Definition 4]
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item[] 
      \item Six
      \item Seven
    \end{enumerate}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: In my document, this still puts a dot on the same line as the definition where it thinks the first (empty) list item is. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check to see if you forgot the square brackets `[]` after of `\item`.  Put `\item[]` is very important. This also works for `enumerate`.

Comment: And you don't need modify your specifications with `\setlist[...]{...}`.