# Items in itemize aren't on the text area

Tags: itemize, tabularx

Good morning

I've got this source code below. The problem is the item `item` in `itemize` isn't in the text area but it's out of the text area. I try to get `$$` on every `\item` line but the result is the same. I have replaced a black ball mark with text. Result is on the picture.

Thank you for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,
 bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy 


%************************************************************
\newpage
%************************************************************

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Opytovacie zámená}}

\begin{itemize}

  \item[kto? koho?] %$ $ 
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
      \toprule  
      {\sffamily who?}           & {\sffamily which of?} \\
      \textsl{[\textipa{hu:}]}   & \textsl{[\textipa{wItS 6v}]}  \\
      \bottomrule
      všeobecne                  & z určitého počtu osôb\\
    \end{tabular}

    \item[čo?]  %$ $    
      \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
        \toprule  
        {\sffamily what?}           & {\sffamily which?} \\
        \textsl{[\textipa{hu:}]}   & \textsl{[\textipa{wItS}]}  \\
        \bottomrule
        všeobecne                  & z určitého počtu vecí\\
     \end{tabular}

     \begin{itemize}
       \item vždy keď nasleduje predložka {\sffamily of}
     \end{itemize}

    \item[aký? ktorý?]  %$ $    
      \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
        \toprule  
        {\sffamily what?}           & {\sffamily which of?} \\
        \bottomrule
        všeobecne                  & z určitého počtu osôb a vecí\\
     \end{tabular}  

    \item[koľko]    %$ $     
      \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
        \toprule  
        {\sffamily how much?}           & {\sffamily how many?} \\
        \textsl{[\textipa{haU m2tS}]}   & \textsl{[\textipa{haU \textprimstress men.i}]}  \\
        \bottomrule
        s ne\-po\-čí\-ta\-teľ\-ný\-mi pod\-sta\-tný\-mi menami                  & s počítateľnými podstatnými menami\\
     \end{tabular}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192480/force-itemize-inside-description-onto-a-new-line, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298085/how-to-avoid-underfull-boxes-in-itemize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,
 bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy 


%************************************************************
\newpage
%************************************************************

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Opytovacie zámená}}

\begin{description}

  \item[kto? koho?] \mbox{}

    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
      \toprule  
      {\sffamily who?}           & {\sffamily which of?} \\
      \textsl{[\textipa{hu:}]}   & \textsl{[\textipa{wItS 6v}]}  \\
      \bottomrule
      všeobecne                  & z určitého počtu osôb\\
    \end{tabular}

    \item[čo?] \mbox{}  %$ $ 

      \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
        \toprule  
        {\sffamily what?}           & {\sffamily which?} \\
        \textsl{[\textipa{hu:}]}   & \textsl{[\textipa{wItS}]}  \\
        \bottomrule
        všeobecne                  & z určitého počtu vecí\\
     \end{tabular}

     \begin{itemize}
       \item vždy keď nasleduje predložka {\sffamily of}
     \end{itemize}

    \item[aký? ktorý?] \mbox{} 

      \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
        \toprule  
        {\sffamily what?}           & {\sffamily which of?} \\
        \bottomrule
        všeobecne                  & z určitého počtu osôb a vecí\\
     \end{tabular}  

    \item[koľko] \mbox{} 

      \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
        \toprule  
        {\sffamily how much?}           & {\sffamily how many?} \\
        \textsl{[\textipa{haU m2tS}]}   & \textsl{[\textipa{haU \textprimstress men.i}]}  \\
        \bottomrule
        s ne\-po\-čí\-ta\-teľ\-ný\-mi pod\-sta\-tný\-mi menami                  & s počítateľnými podstatnými menami\\
     \end{tabular}

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you leave a blank/empty/without comments line between `\mbox{}` and `\begin{tabular`?